# Have any meaning $\int_0^{x} x dt$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

If $x$ and $t$ are independent variables, does this expression have any meaning?

$$\int_0^{x} x \hspace{2pt}\mathrm{d}t$$

I admit that I'm confused about this!

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Sure. You can substitute any numerical value for $x$, such as $x=42$, and you get $\int_0^{42} 42 \, dt = 42^{2}$.

Comment: It's just another way to write $x^2$ unless "mining" means something else

Comment: Think of $x$ as a constant in this context. Integrate with respect to $t$. You will not run into any difficulties.

Comment: @LeeMosher x is a real variable, not a fixed number.

Comment: @NNN Yes, $x$ is a real variable, but if you're integrating with respect to $t$ and $x$ has no relation to $t$, then $x$ is a constant with respect to $t$, so you should treat it like a constant in this integration.

Comment: A real variable is a symbol that can be substituted with a real number. I gave the example of substituting $x=42$. It was only one example substitution. Any other substitution is valid, such as $x=\pi$, or $x=(127-\sqrt{894}) / \sin(3.298 \pi)$. And as pointed out in the comment of @Brenton, the value of the integral will always come out to be $x^2$, no matter what value of $x$ you substitute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. Say $x=2$. That would amount to

$$\int\limits_0^2 2 \, dt = 2 \cdot \int\limits_0^2 1\,dt=2\cdot\left[t\right]_0^2=2\cdot(2-0)=2^2=4$$

More generally, we have:

$$\int\limits_0^x x \, dt = x \cdot \int\limits_0^x 1\,dt=x\cdot\left[t\right]_0^x=x\cdot(x-0)=x^2$$

Comment: But $x$ is a real variable.

Comment: But you're integrating with respect to $t$, not to $x$. In the context the expression shows up, does $x$ depend on $t$? If the answer is no, then $x$ may be treated as a constant with respect to integration over $t$.

Comment: Thanks, but what happen when $x$ depends on $t$?

Comment: @NNN, that's a completely different case, and you should've made it clear in the question

Comment: Yes, I asked it just for curious! Do you know about this?

Comment: @NNN, If $x$ is a function of $t$, then what you probably have here are two unrelated symbols: the function $x(t)$ and a variable $x$.  More likely though is that the variable name was a bad choice in the first place; since you are integrating $dt$, it makes a lot more sense if the variable is somehow related to $t$.

Comment: @DanBryant And so we can't say something like: $\int_{0}^{x}xdx$ ?

Comment: @NNN, You can write that expression, but it's confusing, since $x$ and $x$ are different symbols in the above expression.  It's clearer to just relabel one of them.

Comment: @DanBryant Thank you very much.

Comment: The thing is that if $x$ depends on $t$, then the expression doesn't really make sense; that's because the limits of integration should never depend on the variable of integration. You can have something like:

$$f(t)=\int_0^{x(t)}x(s)\,ds$$

However, if you write it as:

$$f(t)=\int_0^{x(t)}x(t)\,dt$$

then you're just making the expression ambiguous and poorly defined: is the $t$ in $x(t)$ inside the integral varying with the $t$ that's being integrated, or is it the fixed $t$ from $f(t)$? Does that make the difference clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, from the point of view of the integral $x$ is a constant, so we have $$\int_0^xx\;dt=x\int_0^x1\;dt=x\left(\left.t\right|_{t=0}^{t=x}\right)=x(x-0)=x^2$$

Comment: But $x$ is a real variable.

Comment: I just said from the point of view of the integral.  You can factor it out, which I will show.

Answer (score 2):

If, $x$ is a variable, then you mean to have something like

$$f(x)=\int_0^x xdt.$$

This notation is not common, however. Usually, the integrand and bounds do not use the same variable name, unless one is a constant, as is not the case here.

For examples, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral). This page shows various trigonemtric integrals, such as $$\mathrm{Si}(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$

Answer (score 2):

The confusion was you stated them as *independent* variables which implies there is no relationship between $x$ and $t$ and as far as the integral over $t$ is concerned $x$ is a constant that can be taken outside.

If $x$ and $t$ are *dependen*t variables, say $x = x(t)$ then the correct way (that leaves no room for confusion) to right your integral is as $\int_0^{x(t)} x(t') dt'$.